# Namespace issue with WCF Messagecontract

Tags: wcf, namespaces, datacontract, messagecontract

We have developed a WCF which uses message contracts as parameters. When I am generated WSDL for them, for some of the Message contracts the WCF is adding http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ Namesapce, even though I am overriding the namespace attribute for MessageContract with my custom namespace. Please help me in overriding the default namespace (http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/).

Here is sample code for the Contracts and WSDL

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace="http://www.example.com/unh0/xwds/wd/service/0")]
public class WithholdingDeterminationLiteService : IWithholdingDeterminationLiteService 
{   
    public withholdingDeterminationResponse WithholdingDeterminationLite(withholdingDeterminationLiteRequest request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
}



[MessageContract(WrapperNamespace = "http://www.example.com/unh0/xwds/wd/lite/request/1")]
public class withholdingDeterminationLiteRequest : baseVersionableType
{

    …
    private withholdingDeterminationLiteRequestTrade tradeField;

    …

    /// <remarks/>
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://example.com/xods/common/1")]
    public withholdingDeterminationLiteRequestTrade trade
    {
        Get  { return this.tradeField; } set { this.tradeField = value; }
    }

    …
}
```

WSDL Generated out of this has

```
 <wsdl:definitions  …>
    <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/unh0/xwds/wd/lite/request/1">
    <xsd:element name="withholdingDeterminationLiteRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
    …
    <xsd:element xmlns:q2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" minOccurs="1" name="trade" type="q2:withholdingDeterminationLiteRequestTrade"/>
    …
    </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
    …
    <xsd:complexType name="withholdingDeterminationLiteRequestTrade">
    …
    </xs

d:complexType>
<xsd:element name="withholdingDeterminationLiteRequestTrade" type="tns:withholdingDeterminationLiteRequestTrade"/>
..
</xsd:schema>

</wsdl:types>
…
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your base types are in the same namespace?

Comment: My base type baseVersionableType is in http://example.com/xods/common/1 namespace..    [MessageContract(WrapperNamespace = "http://www.example.com/xods/common/1")]
    public class baseVersionableType
    {

        private string schemaVersionField;
        [MessageBodyMember()]
        public string schemaVersion
        {
            get { return this.schemaVersionField; } set { this.schemaVersionField = value; }
        }
    }

Comment: What type is withholdingDeterminationLiteRequestTrade?

Comment: [DataContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/unh0/xwds/wd/lite/request/1")]
    public class withholdingDeterminationLiteRequestTrade
    { ... }